# Python Keystroke / Mouseclick Refference, codes list?

Tags: python, function, binding, tkinter, calculator

I'm currently "programming" a simple calculator in Python, created all the labels 
and the general "outlook" of the calculator.

I need to create binding functions so that when a label e.g. `"1"` is pressed it is added to the string that is to be executed.

I know how to create a binding function that emulates all three button clicks (), enter and left and right arrows but I have no idea how to define the numbers and symbols, so, if someone had a reference sheet with all the numbers, symbols and letters it would be great.

Comment: Depends on what GUI library you're using. What GUI library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tkinter, most event strings for keyboard presses simply correspond to the symbol of the key. For example, to trigger an event when the "1" key is pressed, do:

```
root.bind("1", some_function)
```

(Note that this is different from `root.bind("<1>", some_function)` - the brackets indicate that the event is referring to the first mouse button.)

You can do the same for your typical artihmetic operators:

```
root.bind("+", some_function)
root.bind("-", some_function)
root.bind("*", some_function)
root.bind("/", some_function)
root.bind("=", some_function)
```

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. How do I give you points for the answer?